# HtmlAgilityPack LoadFromBrowser method not found

Tags: html-agility-pack

I am using `HtmlAgilityPack 1.6.2` within a `.NET Core 2.0` Console application. `HtmlWeb.Load` function works fine but `LoadFromBrowser` function is not available. I got a compiler error. The testing code is copied from the [tutorial page](http://html-agility-pack.net/from-browser) so it should be correct. Please advise how to use the API.

Answer (score 1):

The `LoadFromBrowser` method requires the WinForm `WebBrowser` to work.

Since there is not `WebBrowser` in `.NET Core 2.0`, this method is not available.

This method could be available in the future by replacing the `WebBrowser` by an open source browser but there is currently no short-term plan for it.

**EDIT: Answer comment**

> Is there still no solution for this?

I didn't try it, but some package support web browser for .NET Standard such as : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver

So perhaps if you use this package to retrieve the HTML and use it with HAP, that will work.

Comment: Is there still no solution for this?

Comment: @Jonathan Magnan...has this been implemented for the later versions of .NET Core (i.e. 2.2 or 3)  or is there some other library you can direct me too as I cant seem to find anything else of use. Also, whay doesn't the method LoadFromWebAsync, not wait for all the content to load?

Comment: Did you try Selenium.WebDriver to get the HTML @dinotom?

Answer (score -1):

I have the same prob, installed Selenium.WebDriver, but don't know how to use it with HAP to wait until JS is loaded.

Comment: This is not an answer and can actually be added as a comment to the question.